# Redirect path depend on resolver class with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I trying to redirect the user when a slug don't match with API.

My app.routes.ts

```
{
    path: ':region-slug',
    component: RegionComponent,
    resolve: {
        region: RegionResolver
    }
}
```

The resolver (region.resolver.ts) :

```
@Injectable()
export class RegionResolver implements Resolve<any>{

  constructor(private regionsService: RegionsService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {

    return this.regionsService.getRegion(route.params['region-slug']);
  }
}
```

The service which serves me the region (region.service.ts) :

```
@Injectable()
export class RegionsService {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  getRegion(slug: string) {

    return Observable.create(observer => {

      setTimeout(() => {
        observer
          .next(regions.find((region) => region.slug == slug))
          .complete();

      }, 1000);

    });
  }
}
```

How i can handle an error to put a : `this.router.navigate(['/']);` and where I'm suppose to implement this (in resolver class no) ? Thx

Comment: Ok, the redirection must be done by the resolver. I added a do oparator after my getRegion() which redirect if region is undefined : `return this.regionsService.getRegion(route.params['region-slug']).do(region => {
        if (!region) {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
      });`